# Pluralization with default_locale not working in Rails4 Beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, ruby-on-rails-4, pluralize

I am just trying to setup an application in Rails 4, Beta 1. The application in (exclusively) in German and therefore also the URLs should be German.
I want to create a controller and model for an entity called "Region"; Rails pluralizes that to "Regions", but it should be "Regionen".
What I did is:
in config/application.rb uncomment this line:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

And in config/initializers/inflections.rb I put this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:de) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'region', 'regionen'
end
```

But its not working...
When I change the inflection to

```
inflect.irregular 'region', I18n.locale
```

and remove the (:de) I can see that the passed locale is :en and not :de.
Why is my default locale not passed to this inflections?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it several times...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is the case (I have the same problem), but try also this:

```
config.i18n.locale = :de
```